# FileMaker global list field

Tags: filemaker

I'm trying to create a multi select function by adding and removing record IDs into a global field.

I've created a global field called current_selection.

I attached a script action to the name field that is suppose to add or remove the record id to the global field.

```
If ( PatternCount ( committee::current_selection; committee::id & "¶"); Substitute ( committee::current_selection; committee::id &"¶"; "¶"); committee::id & "¶" &committee::current_selection)
```

and that is how i set the global field.

Meanwhile I set conditional formatting for the name field for a visual of what is selected

```
PatternCount ( committee::current_selection; committee::id & ¶)
```

so what happens is 1 is selected when 11 is selected then if I click 1 it takes 1 off 11

Not sure why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `"1"` is included in `"11"`, so your test produces a false positive. And substituting `"1¶"` out of `"11¶"` leaves `"1"`.

To see if an item exists in a list of return-separated values, use:

```
IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( item ; listOfValues ) )
```

---

Removing an item from a list is more difficult than it might seem. Start with:

```
Substitute ( ¶ & listOfValues & ¶ ; ¶ & item & ¶ ; ¶ )
```

then remove the extra carriage returns from the result.

Comment: +1 Michael. I usually enclose values in xml like tags, so it is easier to match and remove: e.g. <item>1</item> vs  <item>11</item>